# How to get a fixed header in a partially fluid page?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page with a wrapper that restricts the width between min and max width. I would like to have a fixed header (that does not scroll), that re-sizes to the available width of the wrapper.

See JSFiddle here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arjunk/cnme2b78/3/)

I've set the width as 100% but that takes 100% of the whole document. **I cannot use CSS3**.

### Code:

#### HTML:

```
<div id="Wrapper">
    <div id="Main">
        <div id="MMenu">
           Main Menu Bar
        </div>
    </div>
    Content...
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
#Wrapper {   
    position:relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width:100px;
    max-width:500px;
    background-color: White;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px; 
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align: left;
    border-left:1px solid gray;
    border-right:1px solid gray;
}

#MMenu {
    background-color:#cccccc;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 30px;
    width:100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: `position:fixed` takes out of the *document flow*. So this is the only solution: `width` on the `#Main` and `width:inherit` on the `#MMenu`. http://jsfiddle.net/cnme2b78/4/.

Comment: That doesn't work - you added `width:500px;` to the Main div also, so it seemed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need to add an extra layer of HTML, which I'd called `.header`.

#### HTML:

```
<div id="Wrapper">
    <div id="Main">
        <div id="MMenu">
           <div class="header">Main Menu Bar</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    Content...
</div>
```

Second you'll need some CSS changes:

#### CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
}

.header {
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    max-width: 520px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    left: 0;
}
```

#### [Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankushkk/2cxdn8vb/1/)

---

### EDIT:

This works except for adding horizontal scroll bars. If you switch the wrapper to `position:absolute`, remove the `width`, use `max-width`s `margin: 0 auto;` centering, you can remove these.

#### [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2cxdn8vb/4/)

Comment: Only code issue here is that there are horizontal scroll bars due to setting the width to `100%` and having padding. Fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/2cxdn8vb/4/. However, this is a link only answer. The code needs to be in the answer in case JSFiddle ever closes up.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
#MMenu {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    width: inherit; /*add this*/
    z-index: 5;
}

#Main {
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: sorry 
I forgot to write that you need to set the width of the parent then it will work

Comment: Won't that fix the header width to 800px then? The header must resize to the width of the wrapper.

Comment: sorry change width at max-width

Comment: use max-width: 500px; in #Main

Comment: It doesn't work. Wrapper min-width is set to 100px. So the main menu bar must always be centered between the two black lines.

Comment: hmm ... you have the same wrapper itself is not adaptive, it may be to start to do the adaptive and only then to take for a fixed menu?

Comment: Almost works. But watch the right edge of the header as the size gets smaller. Nevermind, @Ankush has solved it.

Answer (score 0):

give it the same values

```
#Mmenu{
  max-width: 520px /* you have 500px max width and 10px padding left and right */
  margin-left:-10px /* to center those 20px */
}
```